# Jump from building: die from shock induced heart failure before hitting the ground?

Tags: biology, cardiology, mortality

In my childhood days there was this proposition/myth that claimed there is a big chance that you'd die from a shock induced heart failure (hart attack/cardiac arrest) before hitting the ground, when jumping off a building (for suicide or for escaping a fire for instance).

Is there any validity to this claim?

Comment: Please feel free to add some more relevant tags to this question, as I don't have enough rep. to create original tags.

Comment: Hey, I also remember to got this story told from another kid when I was little. I'm from Germany, so dependent from where the OP is this might be actually quite wide spread.

Comment: This really depends on what you consider dead. People have been without a heartbeat for many minutes and been revived with no ill-effects.

Comment: I think there is a more likely chance you would faint, then die as you hit the ground.

Comment: A query - why do skydivers not die? They fall an awfully long way. Or if it is a proximity thing, why do bungee jumpers or cliff divers survive?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I'm from The Netherlands. So I'm in close vicinity.

Comment: @Rory Alsop: Yes, I considered this too. Although those people have a reasonable expectation to survive the 'ordeal'. :) People with no safety net, can reasonably expect to die from it, which might lead to a shock.

Comment: I am deleting my answer because A) I haven't cited, and B) after having done some research, I now think I was wrong. :)

Comment: Skydivers don't die because they have a parachute which they know will save them. Jumping off a building the result is inevitable, splat. But learner parachute jumpers do go tandem so they don't panic, pass out and have the same result, splat.

Comment: @Craig: Passing out and dying are completely unrelated. Also, suicidal persons *expect* to die when jumping off a building. Why should they panic?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker if you pass out when skydiving, you can't open the parachute and you die, so i don't agree that it's unrelated. Btw, there are people jumping and regretting their decision instantly, maybe those can panic.

Comment: @djerry: If you pass out, you don't die before hitting the ground. Which is what the question is about and what I meant by my first sentence.

Comment: Even if you have a heart attack, you don't die immediately. People survive for hours with them. Even if your heart stops it takes a couple of minutes to technically die. You've got to fall about four miles for that to get you before the fall.

Comment: If they are blind, their ears have been cut out, and their sensory nerves fried, I doubt they'd die of shock. (If they have not died from the lack of functioning sensory nerves.)

Answer (score 7):

There are a handfull of instances of people surviving much higher falls from plane crashes. [Vesna Vulović](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesna_Vulovi%C4%87) is one such person. [The Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2587/could-you-jump-off-a-bridge-or-a-tall-building-and-survive-the-fall) also mentions a case were someone survived a jump from the Golden Gate Bridge.

From this we can safely conclude that that if it was indeed the shock that kills, It definitely doesn't occur 100% of the time, so it is at best plausible. Going further than that to definitively prove the claim false in most or all cases is exceedingly difficult since the trauma caused by impact would overshadow evidence of cardiac arrest during an autopsy.